# passing variable to loop as string in python

Tags: python, unix

I have a python script that will take each file in a directory, iterate through the contents of the file and create an output file for each input file. This output file may have duplicate entries and if it does I would like to take only the unique values similar to the UNIX command

```
uniq -u input.file > output.file
```

Although I could use shell scripts to do this I would like to include a line of python that will take only unique values. I know i can do this:

```
import os
os.system("uniq -u input.file > output.file")
```

However when I attempt to put this in a loop so that it will make unique all of the files I just made:

```
for curfile in fs:
    if curfile[-3:]=='out':
        os.system("uniq -u %s > %s") % (str(curfile), str(curfile[:-4] + ".uniq")
```

I get the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I have tried a few syntaxes to try to get the variables recognized but can't find a similar enough example on the web. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've forgotten a `)` in `os.system("uniq -u %s > %s") % (str(curfile), str(curfile[:-4] + ".uniq")`.

Comment: the parenthesis for os.system should encolose all of the rest of line, shouldnt it?

Comment: It's not just a missing paren -- you've also got one in the wrong place.

Comment: Note that ideally, you should be using `subprocess.call()` instead of `os.system()`.

Comment: why is subprocess.call() better? would be glad to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
os.system(
             "uniq -u %s > %s"
         ) % ( # The % and this paren should be inside the call to os.system
                 str(curfile), 
                 str(curfile[:-4] + ".uniq")
               # you're missing a close paren here
```

you need

```
os.system(
             "uniq -u %s > %s" % (
                                     str(curfile), 
                                     str(curfile[:-4] + ".uniq")
                                 )
         )
```

First you format the string, *then* it goes to `os.system` -- as you have it now, the string goes to `os.system` then you attempt to `%` the result, which is an `int`. (The return code of `uniq`.)